# Redux trigger action from the component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am enjoy learning redux and applying it to my current project. got a question in my mind. at the moment action is pass down from the props. Just wondering can i import action and call action? because i may have nested nested component keep pass down the props may not be ideal would nice to trigger action at deeply level without pass down the props down.

Any suggestions appreciated :)

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class ButtonGroup extends Component{
    static PropTypes = {
        actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <button className="button" onClick={ e => { this.props.actions.popForm()}}>Create New</button>
        );      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you're describing, you need to use `connect` from [react-redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#quick-start).

So, in your example:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

export class ButtonGroup extends Component{
    static PropTypes = {
        popForm: PropTypes.function.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <button className="button" onClick={ e => { this.props.popForm()}}>Create New</button>
        );      
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(ButtonGroup);
```

Comment: basically just using connect with actions? I will try it out myself.

Comment: `e => { this.props.popForm()}` is not good because 1. you loose event object ( `e`) by not passing it to `popForm`. 2. you create new handler during each rendering 3. it's not very readable.

Comment: simply: `onClick={this.props.popForm}` would be enough (although in your example  example you bind implicitly handler's `this` to component's `this.props`, I assume that in most cases wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @hex13 export default connect(null, actions)(ButtonGroup); is correct way to go?